# Is it possible to stop Django adding quotes around raw SQL params?

Tags: django

Django's raw SQL feature adds single quote marks around any parameters you pass into the SQL query, if the parameters are strings.

This breaks for me when I need to do a query like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (%s)`

The param is a string, such as '1,2,3', so Django renders the query as:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('1,2,3')`

Those quotes around the param break the query.

It seems to me Django is forcing me to use string interpolation (ie injecting the params into the string before it's used in the raw query), yet the docs clearly state we should not do that.

From the docs:

> Using the params argument completely protects you from SQL injection
>   attacks, a common exploit where attackers inject arbitrary SQL into
>   your database. If you use string interpolation, sooner or later you’ll
>   fall victim to SQL injection. As long as you remember to always use
>   the params argument you’ll be protected.

Is there a way to turn OFF the quotes? If we want quotes we can just add them, no? (eg WHERE name = '%s')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django raw query takes in [parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) as a single list or dictionary. So in this case, you should be invoking your raw query like this:

`YourModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in %s', [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)])`

Comment: Ah I see. It accepts a list of integers. I was thinking I had to format the list of integers as a string, which is how I was getting the quote marks.