# Django | Create table raw query execution with query param

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, syntax

Can please somebody tell me whats wrong about my Syntax?
I try since 2 days to get a decent answer on this matter, but wether people just give me minus points or refer me to to the Django docs I already read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/

```
tablename = '2020-10-table'
v_col = ["userID int(11)", "TID varchar(128)", "CID varchar(128)", "SID varchar(255)", "Timestamp bigint(20)", "LX int(10)", "LocY int(10)", "Width int(10)", "Height int(10)", "Tag varchar(512)"]

connection.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%s` %s""", [tablename, '( '+str(', '.join(v_col))+' )'])
```

I keep receiving this:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ''( userID int(11), TI
>   ......

Can anyone please point out my issue?

UPDATE:

I figured out that Django processes my string internally as bytestring:

```
b"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'2020-10-table'` '(userID int(11), TID varchar(128), CID varchar(128), SID varchar(255), Timestamp bigint(20), LX int(10), LocY int(10), Width int(10), Height int(10), Tag varchar(512))'"
```

which is obviously no valid sql?!?

Now I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

First i think you should not to use '%s', if these quotes around the %s because this leaves your database free for sql injection attacks

Second i think you have to use connection.cursor like this:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s %s""", [tablename, '( '+str(', 
      '.join(v_col))+' )'])
```

Comment: I do not use single quotes. The problem is that I have to use backticks, since I use a tablename including a minus sign. I figured that Django uses single quotes to escape all %s which is by my usage against the sql syntax. All the `( v_col_values )` are surrounded by singlequotes, which is no sql syntax. As a good example one can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942736/is-it-possible-to-stop-django-adding-quotes-around-raw-sql-params ,but it doen'st explain to me how i can handle my strings without single quotes.

Comment: Oh, i see now, i search and seems like there is no way to pass fields into a query, only parameters, i don't even know if this will work by the way django creates tables in models